# nginx in docker proxy path to subdomain

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

What I want is to forward all requests made for:

www.domain.com/**api**/whaterver/comes/next to -> **api**.domain.com/whatever/comes/next

The reason is to avoid browser CORS for www.domain.com requesting to api.domain.com

**Probably worth mentioning that nginx is running in a Docker container.**

I am trying to accomplish with the location block below, but it fails:

```
server {
listen 8443 ssl;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/base/public;

location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host api.domain.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://api.domain.com/$1;
}

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
ssl_session_timeout         5m;
ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common.conf;
}
```

Comment: You missed `~` sign: `location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {`

Comment: Try changing the host header to the new `api.domain.com` with `proxy_set_header Host api.domain.com;` ?

Comment: And @Zac is right too, I forgot that HTTP `Host` header also should be changed...

Comment: @IvanShatsky still nothing, I get back my 404 response. Adding both your suggestions.

Comment: @Zac still nothing

Comment: I didn't see any other errors, are you sure that you did not have any conflicts with other `location` blocks? Maybe it worth to test this config with only this one `location`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky it is the only one. I've edited with the server block.

Comment: I just tried your config at my sandbox. We forgot one more thing - to specify a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver). Use `8.8.8.8` for example if you didn't have you own.

Comment: @IvanShatsky does this work if my nginx is inside a container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201143/discussion-between-ivan-shatsky-and-mallix).

Comment: Try replacing `proxy_pass https://api.domain.com/$1;` with `return 301 https://api.example.com/$1` . In one of my servers I've worked with, I did a similar redirect by doing this `return 301 https://www.example.com` give that shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan for pointing me to the right direction on this one.

The resolver inside a Docker container should use the Docker embedded DNS server at 127.0.0.11 with the ipv6 directive switched off:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/base/public;

    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://api.domain.com/$1;
    }

}
```