# Nginx revers proxy can't reach docker container by host name

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Nginx reverse proxy can't reach docker host. Hosting on amazon (EC2)
I want to load different apps depends on location.

nginx.conf

```
server { 
 listen 80 ;
 server_name localhost;
 location /web {
  proxy_pass http://web:4000/;
 }}
```

Location works and it means that nginx image builded correct either.

docker-compose file

```
services:
 web:
  image: web
  container_name: web
  ports:
   - 4000:4000
  hostname: web
  networks:
   - default
 nginx:
  image: nginx
  container_name: nginx
  ports:
   - 80:80                                                         
  depends_on:
  - web
  networks:
   - default
networks:
  default:
   external:
    name: my-network
```

I expect 
- when I type in url /web it should show app from docker container

I've tried

```
  Run single container - works fine (web or nginx) 
  Added 127.0.0.1 web in /etc/hosts (I can do 'curl web' but it shows localhost response)
  Added index index.html in location section
  Added resolver in the location section
  Use links instead of network
```

When "docker-compose up" I can inspect docker container (web) and see IP - 192.168.10.2 . Then  `curl 192.168.10.2` shows me index.html. But I can't make `curl http://web:4000` seems that hostname in unreachable, but I think that using IP in proxy_pass is a bad decision.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466891/nginx-in-docker-proxy-path-to-subdomain) question/discussion, maybe it can help you?

Comment: I’d simplify the `docker-compose.yml` by deleting all of the `networks:`, `hostname:`, and `container_name:` blocks; does that make a difference at all?  If the `my-network` network has another container named `web` that’s not listening on port 4000 that could cause the issue you’re seeing; the actual connection error from nginx would be helpful for diagnosing further.

Comment: BTW: you don't need to publish port 4000. Containers in the same network can always communicate internally on all ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to handle those issues, so I've chose another approach.

Create network ipam

```
 docker network create --gateway 172.20.0.1 --subnet 172.20.0.0/24 ipam
```

Assigned for each service ipv4address in docker-compose file

```
networks:
  default:
    ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5 for web
where
networks:
   default:
    external:
      name: ipam
```

Add chmod for directory /var/www/html in my web docker image

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

(seems this additional step required if you build LINUX container under windows docker)