# Using nginx, can I remove parent path when proxying to uwsgi/Django server?

Tags: nginx

My goal is to send this to the nginx server:

```
http://www.example.com/secure/rest/rabbits/list?foo=baloo
```

and for the nginx server to reverse proxy this to the django server:

```
/rabbits/list?foo=baloo
```

After many hours fiddling I can find no way to make this happen.

Here are the relevant lines in my nginx config:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

location /secure/rest/ {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
}
```

And the result in the Django log is this:

```
Oct 19 09:47:10 ip-172-26-15-20 uwsgi[51176]: Not Found: /secure/rest/user
```

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work?  I've tried so many solutions from SO that I've lost track of what permutations of solutions I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968482/expose-multiple-api-uri-on-the-same-nginx-server-block/62971843#62971843) answer. It is about the similar problem with the `ngx_http_fastcgi_module`, but I think the reason and solution are the same. You need to manually overwrite `REQUEST_URI` uwsgi parameter after including `uwsgi_params` file with `uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI ...` directive. Try this:

```
location /secure/rest/ {
    rewrite     ^/secure/rest(.*)$ $1 break;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;
    uwsgi_pass  django;
}
```