# Redirect From Subdirectory To Different Subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redirect, digital-ocean

I have a Laravel website that is hosted using DigitalOcean. I would like `www.domain.com/1` to be redirected to `www.domain.com/2`. How can I achieve this? Does this need to be done within my Laravel application, or do I need to do something in my NGINX config file?

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/1$ /2 permanent;` rule.

Comment: Can you please explain? Where do I put that code in my config file?

Comment: Put this rule into the `server` block. It doesn't matter where exactly you put it since directives from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are executed at the rewrite phase of request processing before most of the other directives, for better config readability you can put it before the `location` blocks. This directive will produce 301 HTTP redirect from `/1` to `/2`, if you want to process this URI without redirection, use just `rewrite ^/1$ /2;`

Comment: [Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) is the `rewrite` directive documentation.

Comment: This works. However, what do you mean by "process this URI without redirection"? I tried using `rewrite ^/1$ /2;` first, but that didn't work. When I did `rewrite ^/1$ /2 permanent;`, that worked. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: That means to make nginx process `/1` URI as if it originally was `/2` without extra redirection response. Why it isn't work for you depends on you config, you can try `rewrite ^/1$ /2 break;`, check the documentation.

Comment: Just figured out. Using Lavarel framework means you have some kind of PHP location handler. Usually all the FastCGI parameters are being set with some kind of included file where the line `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri` is present. The `$request_uri` variable is not a subject to change with the `rewrite` directive, it is an `$uri` variable that this directive changes. Exactly this variable is checked by the `rewrite` or `location` directives, but to make changes being seen by underlying PHP backend you should overwrite the `REQUEST_UIR` FastCGI parameter.

Comment: To do it you can add `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;` directive **after** the `fastcgi_params` file (filename could vary upon different distros) is being included. This way you could make this works without generating an extra HTTP 301 redirect response.

Comment: I described this once in some more details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968482/expose-multiple-api-uri-on-the-same-nginx-server-block/62971843#62971843) answer.

Comment: I don't know what can be the cause. From my point of view it should be no difference. Check the nginx logs, maybe the link appeared somehow different from being entered via the browser address bar?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a QR code issue. It still redirects when using chrome. It’s only safari that doesn’t redirect.

Comment: Does this mean I need to process the redirect at the Laravel level and not at the server level?

Comment: It can be a safari cache. Try from the incognito window.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even tried with my friend's phone but it still doesn't redirect.

Comment: I actually tried all browsers (Edge, Safari, Opera, Firefox, DuckDuckGo, Chrome) and they all don't redirect now. Chrome on my computer does.

Comment: Then it looks like you somehow remove that redirection from the nginx config and your home Chrome is the only browser that cached it. Recheck the nginx config. Any backup restored recently (by you or by your hoster)?

Comment: Does this need to go in my server block or nginx config file?

Comment: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com` or `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: Server block of course

Comment: It's in my server block. I tried both `rewrite ^/1$ /2 break;` and `rewrite ^/1$ /2;` and none work. How did this work before but not now? I didn't change anything.

Comment: `rewrite ^/1$ /2 permanent;`, it is in the first comment.

Comment: I tried `rewrite ^/1$ /2 permanent;` first and it didn't work, remember? Anyway, I will try it again and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: It works now. I'm very sorry, I don't know why it stopped working all of a sudden? Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.