# can I redirect different home directories according to urls?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx, apache2

I have 2 codeignitor projects in different directories.

what I want to do is

```
www.url.com => /var/www/ci_project
www.url.com/page1 => /var/www/ci_project

www.url.com/en => /home/another/ci_project
www.url.com/en/page1 => /home/another/ci_project
```

That is, only if the "en/" come followed host we would use different ci project.

However, it seems the apache alias cannot help because the ci mechanism would cover the path.

Can I achieve this by apache2 or nginx?

Comment: It seems that the only difference between those two application is the language, is that correct? If so, you should only have one project and look into using locales to manage such a thing. If not, you probably need to change your url structure to be something like foo.com and en.foo.com and have the second app running on a different sub-domain.

Comment: well, not only the language, but changed many function in the two projects. In fact, they are 2 different git branched.

Comment: how about routes? https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#examples

Comment: Then I think those need to be in different base urls like foo.com/project1 & foo.com/project2/ or like I said one in the main domain and the other in a sub-domain. But maybe someone knows more than me and will give you a definitive answer.

Comment: @Vickel routes in codeigniter might help, but in codeigniter 3 you cant route redirect to external app. In ci4 you can. I suspect this is ci3 because there's not ci4 tag in the original post.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro well that's all indeed very unclear, sometimes there is a big mixup of sub-project or 2 complete different apps. If there are 2 different apps, .htaccess should resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nginx something like this should work:

```
index index.php;

location / {
    root /var/www/ci_project;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # PHP-FPM handler here
    }
}

# without the following location, request to 'www.url.com/en'
# would be redirected with HTTP 301 code to 'www.url.com/en/'
location = /en {
    rewrite ^ /en/ last;
}

location /en/ {
    # remove the '/en' URI prefix.
    rewrite ^/en(/.*) $1 break;
    root /home/another/ci_project;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^/en(/.*) $1 break;
        # PHP-FPM handler here
    }
}
```

Note two nested PHP handler locations, they needed because each of them should use its own root.

I'm not familiar with the codeignitor, if it relies on the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI parameter to determine the requested route, that one won't be changed with the `rewrite` nginx directive and you'd need to strip the `/en` URI prefix manually (check the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968482/expose-multiple-api-uri-on-the-same-nginx-server-block/62971843#62971843) answer). Here is an example how it can be done:

```
map $request_uri $fixed_uri {
    ~^/en(/.*)$    $1;
}

server {
    ...
    location /en/ {
        # remove the '/en' URI prefix.
        rewrite ^/en(/.*) $1 break;
        root /home/another/ci_project;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            rewrite ^/en(/.*) $1 break;
            # PHP-FPM handler here
            ...
            # this line should be AFTER the default fastcgi parameters file inclusion
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fixed_uri;
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

[This](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/) official page can also be useful to check for some examples.

Comment: I almost  forget to tag you are the correct answer. Thank you so much!! you save my time SO MUCH!!!!