# nginx rewrite slug to querystring without changing url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a slug to a querystring in nginx without changing the browser url.

In Apache the following works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/theblog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /theblog/blog?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In nginx I've tried both of the following:

```
rewrite ^\/theblog\/((?!blog?)[^\/]+)$ /theblog/blog?slug=$1 break;

rewrite ^\/theblog\/((?!blog?)[^\/]+)$ /theblog/blog?slug=$1 last;
```

They both **REDIRECT** to the querystring version of the url, which "*works*" but isn't what i want.  I don't want to change the url in the browser.

I want the url to stay: http://example.com/theblog/test

Not redirect to: http://example.com/theblog/blog?slug=test

Even though that is the resource being requested.

The site is static html with javascript fetching the data, php is not even enabled for this domain.

This server is using:
Plesk Obsidian 18.0.36
Nginx 1.20.1

Hopefully that makes sense.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both of those `rewrite` directives should not lead to redirect but to internal URI rewrite. It is possible that this redirect is generated by your backend. If your backend is a PHP application, you can try to alter the `REQUEST_URI` PHP-FPM parameter:

```
rewrite ^\/theblog\/((?!blog?)[^\/]+)$ /theblog/blog?slug=$1 last;

...

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    include fastcgi_params;
    # default "fastcgi_params" file contains the following line:
    # fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    # now we should overwrite it with a new value:
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;
    ...
}
```

Read the very first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971843/7121513) answer for additional details.

Comment: That's what i though from my reading, but it redirects instead of rewrites.

The site is static html with javascript fetching the data, php is not even enabled for this domain.

This server is using:
Plesk Obsidian 18.0.36
Nginx 1.20.1

I've updated the question with those details.  Should I try adding that anyway?  Or am I experiencing a different issue?  Thanks for the help!