# The easiest way to convince Apache or NGinx to call a function to rewrite URLs

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I think I know at least part of the answer, but I'm not quite there....
I have a need to rewrite URLs coming into a web server (Apache or NGinx, either is fine for me to use).  The URL would be something like this:

```
https/https://myserver.mydomain.com?parm1=xxxxxx?parm2=yyyyy
```

Where xxxx and yyyy are specific values sent in from the client.  Since the parameters could be of many types and values, the normal rewrite rules, including regex won't really cut it.  What I would like to do is:

1. When the URL comes in, look at the URL, if it doesn't match a pattern, process it normally.
2. On pattern match, look that URL up in a table and find the new URL
3. Look up the first parameter in a table for that URL, and rewrite it's parameter name and value
4. Look up the second parameter in the table, and rewrite its name and value
5. If a parameter in the list does not exist in the table, just pass it on
6. Send an HTTP 302 with the new URL and parameters

So if we have mappings like:

```
URL=myserver->newserver.com parm1=imsi=311123456->user=bob parm2=imei=41124122->model=Green
```

An incoming URL such as *http://myserver?imsi=311123456?imei=41124122?extra=yes* would become *http 302 "http://newserver.com?user=bob?model=Green?extra=yes*.

Can I do this with rewrite rules? It doesn't look like it -- since I have to consult tables, this feels like a job for PHP/DJango/Play?  Or am I making it harder than it has to be?

Comment: Should 2 actually read "On pattern match, look that *host* up in a table and find the new *host*", such that particular servers (like `myserver`) map to specific new servers (like `newserver`)? If you have a mapping of complete old -> complete new URLs somewhere, 3 and 4 would not be necessary ... ?  In any case, if there are many of these old -> new mappings then your guess is right, they are more suited to a DB, which you can't access from the web server.  Better to have a front index file which handles everything, and issues just 1 redirect when done.

Comment: (assuming there is no generaliseable pattern to the redirects, which your example seems to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very powerful [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) nginx directive that can do the job like this. Here is an example:

```
map $arg_imsi $user {
    311123456    bob;
    311123457    jane;
    ...
    # default value if none of the above matched will be an empty string
    # however you can use the following part to return some special value
    # if you want to process the non-matching value in a some special way
    ''           '';
    default      unknown;
}
map $arg_imei $model {
    41124122     Green;
    41124123     Red;
    ...
}
```

Unlike apache rewrite rules the `rewrite` nginx directive works with so-called *normalized* URI (see the `location` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to find out what does it mean) which does not include the query part. Usual way to alter the query string is to change the `$args` nginx internal variable:

```
server {
    ...
    if ($args ~ ^(|.*&)imsi=[^&]+(&.*|)$) {
        set $args "${1}user=${user}${2}";
    }
    if ($args ~ ^(|.*&)imei=[^&]+(&.*|)$) {
        set $args "${1}model=${model}${2}";
    }
    ...
}
```

To process those `map` blocks nginx internally used hash tables (which made them quite performant) but to use really big ones you may need to tweak the [`map_hash_bucket_size`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map_hash_max_size) and [`map_hash_max_size`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map_hash_bucket_size) parameters.

You can use regex patterns with the `map` blocks, but there can be some [caveats](https://serverfault.com/a/1036817/498657) where you'll need to use the [named capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) in order to prevent `${1}`, `${2}` etc. variables from being overwritten.

You should be careful if the web app you are serving is some kind of FastCGI/uWSGI app and relies on the `REQUEST_URI` variable to detect the query arguments rather than `QUERY_STRING` one (which is unlikely yet still possible). The default `fastcgi_params` has the following line:

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
```

That `$request_uri` variable contains an original request string including the original query string. In some rare cases you'll need to change that `REQUEST_URI` variable too **after** the `include fastcgi_params;` line in your nginx config (an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971843/7121513)).

Just in case [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1077432/498657) is one more `map` usage example used to solve somehow related yet different rewrite task.