# How to redirect subpaths in nginx with nginx rewrite module?

Tags: php, nginx, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I have a set of url paths which having changed in my application, e.g.:

- /dataview/unknownvvvo/ => /backend/unknown-vvvo
- /dataview/servicecounter => /backend/servicecounter-events

I try to address this with rewrite rules in nginx:

```
user app app;

error_log /dev/stderr debug;

events {}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    rewrite_log on;
    
    charset  utf-8;

    server {
        listen  80;
        listen  [::]:80;

        root  /app/app/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        rewrite ^/dataview/unknownvvvo(.*)$ /backend/unknown-vvvo$1 last;
        rewrite ^/dataview/servicecounter(.*)$ /backend/servicecounter-events$1 last;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /index.php {
            fastcgi_pass  php-fpm_cms:9000;
            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call 'http://localhost/dataview/unknownvvvo' in the browser for example, the nginx error log tells me the rewrite was successful, but it gives me a 404 error:
[nginx_err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rytvu.png)

According to the nginx docs this should work, so what did I miss here?

Comment: If your PHP backend relies on the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI parameter to determine the request URI and/or query arguments, your rewrite rules won't change that parameter - it is set according to the `$request_uri` variable, and that variable does not get changed with the rewrite rules, it is the `$uri` one that does. If you don't want to use HTTP 301 redirects as suggested by Richard Smith, you can try to re-define the `REQUEST_URI` via `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971843/7121513) answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting (with rewrite) from `/dataview/unknownvvvo` to `/backend/unknown-vvvo`, then rewriting (with try_files) from `/backend/unknown-vvvo` to `/index.php`. Your `index.php` script will use the values defined in `fastcgi_params` (probably REQUEST_URI) to determine the requested path - which of course, has not been changed.

The simplest solution is to use an external redirect, using `permanent` instead of `last` on the end of the `rewrite` statements.

```
rewrite ^/dataview/unknownvvvo(.*)$ /backend/unknown-vvvo$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/dataview/servicecounter(.*)$ /backend/servicecounter-events$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Ah okay it was not quite clear to me, that index.php will use the original REQUEST URI, I thought it will use the rewritten URI. I just changed the last flags to permanent and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Changing "last" flags to "permanent" works. But changing fastcgi param REQUEST_URI to *$uri$is_args$args* not:

```
user app app;

error_log /dev/stderr debug;

events {}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    rewrite_log on;

    charset  utf-8;

    server {
        listen  80;
        listen  [::]:80;

        root /app/app/public;
        index index.php index.html;
    
        rewrite ^/dataview/unknownvvvo(.*)$ /backend/unknown-vvvo$1 last;
        rewrite ^/dataview/servicecounter(.*)$ /backend/servicecounter-events$1 last;


        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /index.php {
            fastcgi_pass  php-fpm_cms:9000;
            include       fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

From console output it looks like that still the original request uri is passed to cgi server instead the rewritten one:
[image]

Comment: what worked here is to use the set directive as described here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/805881/nginx-populate-request-uri-with-rewritten-url