# Proxy pass with location regex to docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my application I am using N number (3 in the examples below) of nodes in the same docker network.

The docker-compose of the project looks like the following:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network
services:
  my-node0:
    container_name: node0
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: $PWD/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - my-node-0
  my-node1:
    container_name: node1
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: $PWD/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
      - "9091:9090"
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - my-node-1
  my-node2:
    container_name: node2
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: $PWD/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
      - "9092:9090"
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - my-node-2
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - nginx
    container_name: my-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 3080:80
  frontend:
    container_name: my-frontend
    image: node
    build:
      context: $PWD/frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    external_links:
      - my-node-0
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - my-frontend
    command: npm start
```

I use nginx to help my browser navigate with the docker network alises.
Each node runs 2 different applications, one on port 8080 and one on port 9090, I will call them "first" and "second" from now on.
Previously I used a nginx config like this, and it worked like a charm:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /node0-first {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-0:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    location /node0-second{
        proxy_pass http://my-node-0:9090/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    location /node1-first {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-1:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    location /node1-second{
        proxy_pass http://my-node-1:9090/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    location /node2-first{
        proxy_pass http://my-node-2:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    location /node2-second{
        proxy_pass http://my-node-2:9090/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, if at someday I would like to add, let's say a 1000 nodes, I do not want to add 2000 more location blocks to the config. This is when I came across the possibility of using regexes at at the locations
I have the following, not working, nginx config:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    ##first application
    location ~ ^/node(?<node_number>\d+)-first {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-$node_number:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    ##second application
    location ~ ^/node(?<node_number>\d+)-second {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-$node_number:9090/
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }

    ##testing dynamic rooting
    location ~ ^/test(?<test_number>\d+)$ {
        return 200 "/test$test_number";
    }
  }
}
```

The test route shows me that I am not completely on the wrong path, since it works. Typing http://localhost:3080/test12 returns a "/test12" with the docker log:

```
<IP ADDR> - - [<TIME>] "GET /test12 HTTP/1.1" 200 7 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
```

However sending a request to an existing endpoint on one of my nodes results this:

```
<DATE> <TIME> [error] 31#31: *3 no resolver defined to resolve my-node-1, client: <IP ADDR>, server: localhost, request: "GET /<MY WORKING ENDPOINT> HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3080"
<IP ADDR> - - [<TIME>] "GET /<MY WORKING ENDPOINT> HTTP/1.1" 502 560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
```

Tried to search for an answer, which lead me to a possible solution where I define every node in an upstream block, but than I could just do location blocks instead, that is not what I am looking for.

Than I tried adding the location regex and extra "$" to the end (end of regex, I assume, fairly new with regexes), which made the following bad result:

```
<DATE> <TIME> [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/node1-second/<MY WORKING ENDPOINT>" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: <IP ADDR>, server: localhost, request: "GET /node1-second/<MY WORKING ENDPOINT> HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3080"
<IP ADDR> - - [<TIME>] "GET /node1-second/<MY WORKING ENDPOINT> HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
```

I assume here, since nginx could not find the endpoint (for some reason) it tried to serve a static content, which obviously was not there.

Now comes the question: Is it possible to use proxy passes dynamically this way and if so, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If anyone ever came across the same problem, I managed to do it this way:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    #first application
    location ~ ^/node(?<node_number>\d+)-first/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-$node_number:8080/$2;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    #second applicaton
    location ~ ^/node(?<node_number>\d+)-second/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://my-node-$node_number:9090/$2;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it have matter for you what node receives the request? If not maybe the better way is just to use docker-compose in swarm mode and then set replica that many as you need. But if you need to use Nginx maybe using `map` in config is some tip.

Comment: Sadly it does matter. I did not know about nginx map, I will give it a shot, if I cannot figure something else out, Thanks for it!

Comment: You need a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive in order to use variable hostnames with `proxy_pass`. [Here](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) you can read why it is required. Usually internal resolver for docker containers address is `127.0.0.11` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466891/nginx-in-docker-proxy-path-to-subdomain) question).

Comment: thanks @IvanShatsky it partly solved my issues, but with the resolver and some magic, I managed to do it eventually. I will soon update the post with my solution!

Comment: BTW, there is no need to duplicate `resolver` directive, it should be enough to declare it only once within the `server` context.