# React Application within NGINX Docker cannot call API

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am currently running into a problem with my react application being served by an NGINX docker container. Here are the details:

**My NGINX proxy to my API is working correctly, as I can call it using postman from an external machine.** The problem is that **I cannot call it from within my frontend**. Whenever my frontend makes any request (POST, GET, OPTIONS, etc) into my API, NGINX makes it call 127.0.0.1:8000, which in turn makes the request fail because I am connecting from an external machine which isn't running anything on 127.0.0.1. Even when I set my react application to call the external IP that maps to the proxy, it ends up requesting 127.0.0.1 for some reason.

I don't know if this is an NGINX or a react problem, but I would appreciate any help. I have been trying to solve this issue for quite some time, and even made a previous post that helped me identify the problem correctly, but not the root cause of it.

Here are what my config files look like:

**NGINX: (nginx-proxy.conf)**

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}


server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 192.168.100.6;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT,";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range";
    
    location /api/{  
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';    
        expires off;    
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/react-frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

[Screenshot to firefox networking tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIkSQ.png)

The image in the link above shows all of my website resources being loaded from 192.168.100.6, but the moment I call my API, the request address changes to 127.0.0.1:8000, despite having the react application call 192.168.100.6/api/token (**which does work on postman**).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but can you try `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58471241/7121513)?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of troubleshooting, I have found the problem to my issue.

What actually happened is that all of my codebase was correct, and the proxy was indeed working as intended, but for some reason

> docker-compose build

or even:

> docker-compose build --no-cache

**was not updating my code changes** (it was still sending requests to the ip I was using in development).

The answer that I arrived to was to do:

> docker volume prune "my-nginx-volume"

and then rebuilding through docker-compose.